# Python Selenium checkbox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i am using python 2.7+selenium chromdriver. 
I am trying to automatically check the last checkbox (terms of use) in this page : https://www.insuranceonline.nrma.com.au/oss/GTConnect/UnifiedAcceptor/Portal.Quote?product=Comprehensive&brandId=nrma&_ga=2.57549100.746604201.1512466470-1388355662.1512466470 .

I tried several methods, but still can not get it working. the following method get it checked , but when i click on continue button , it asks me to agree on terms of use although it is checked .

```
browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("f9_chkAgree")[0].checked=true')
```

any help please ?

Thanks.

Comment: please check my answer and let me know your feedback

Comment: provide script you tried, so other can help in different ways

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with python. But the selenium methods are almost same in all languages.

First view the checkbox element.

```
elem = driver.findElement(By.className("chkAgree"));

jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);
```

Then select the checkbox.

```
checkBox = elem.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
checkBox.click();
```

Comment: selenium methods are almost same in all platforms. Please just use the logic above.